Understanding the difference between subgraphs and paths
Working on: Richard Johnsonbaugh. (2024). Discrete Mathematics, 8/e (p. 413)


Find all connected subgraphs of the following graph containing all of the vertices of the original graph and having as few edges as possible. Which are simple paths? Which are cycles? Which are simple cycles?


I have the following definitions in my book:

Definition 8.2.1. Let $v_0$ and $v_n$ be vertices in a graph. A path from $v_0$ to $v_n$ of length $n$ is an alternating sequence of $n+1$ vertices and $n$ edges beginning with vertex $v_0$ and ending with vertex $v_n$: $$(v_0, e_1, v_1, e_2, v_2, \dots, v_{n-1}, e_n, v_n)$$ in which edge $e_i$ is incident on vertices $v_{i-1}$ and $v_i$ for $i=1, \dots, n$.


Definition 8.2.8. Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph. We call $(V', E')$ a subgraph of $G$ if:
(a) $V' \subseteq V$ and $E' \subseteq E$.
(b) For every edge $e' \in E'$, if $e'$ is incident on $v'$ and $w'$, then $v', w' \in V$.


A simple path from $v$ to $w$ is a path from $v$ to $w$ with no repeated vertices.

The question

Which are simple paths/cycles/simple cycles ?

implies that subgraphs and, for example, paths are defined in the same way. However, they are structurally different. A subgraph is not a path, and viceversa.
Am I reading the question correctly ? How do I interpret the given problem ?

Why exactly isn't a path a subgraph?

@schiepy I see a difference. A path denotes a sequence; however, there’s no sequence in a subgraph

I've changed your incredibly long math blocks to actual text, because it was unreadable the way you wrote it.

Thank you @MishaLavrov.

I suspect the definition of "simple path" contains more information than the mere definition of "path". Probably the author intends for you to determine which of the subgraphs are the image of an injective path. Could you provide the definition of "simple path" to your question?

Thank you @Jade Vanadium. I'll update. What do you mean by "image of an injective path" ?

@F.Zer You're very welcome, and thank you too! I meant in the sense that a path is by definition a finite sequence, and a finite sequence is by definition a function with domain ${0,1,2,\cdots,N}$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$. An injective path would then be a path which is injective in the sense of being an injective sequence, i.e. an injective function. This is equivalent to your recently provided definition of simple path :)

And why do you think a subgraph can be understood as being the image of that function @Jade Vanadium ? That image would be a collection of pairs of the form $(V', E')$, i.e. satisfying the definition of subgraph of $G$ ?

@F.Zer Strictly speaking, the image would be $I = {v_0, e_1,v_1,e_2,\cdots}$, which is not really a subgraph... but you can partition the image in an obvious way to get $(I\cap V, I\cap E)$, which really is a subgraph. The conversion from the image into a subgraph is also invertible, as $I=(I\cap V)\cup(I\cap E)$, so no information is lost in the conversion. Because of this, it's subjectively reasonable to conflate the two things under this implicit conversion, despite that they are not literally equal.

You are correct in making a clear distinction, contrary to commenters who claimed otherwise. It is very important to be precise, and the lack of precision in mathematical education is why so few students have a complete understanding. To many, mathematics is mostly about intuitive hand-waving, and there is always lingering doubt about whether you are fully correct or not.
As you stated, rigorously speaking a path is usually defined as a sequence of some specific form, and hence is never a subgraph in any sensible way. However, we are of course interested in the subgraph that corresponds to the path. More precisely, we often want to obtain the subgraph that has exactly the vertices and edges on the path. We can make the commonplace conflation rigorous by permitting type coercion; whenever we use a path P in a sentence about P where it does not make sense for P to be a sequence, we can (by convention) stipulate that P should be coerced to a graph.
One can see similar type ambiguity in other areas of mathematics. For example, in set theory cardinals are often defined as ordinals that do not inject into any smaller ordinal, and so the cardinal $\aleph_0$ would be exactly equal to the ordinal $ω$. However, their notation implies different default type, so $2^{\aleph_0} = \#(\aleph_0→\{0,1\}) = \beth_1$ whereas $2^ω = ω$.
Each expression has a default type that is inferred by its syntax, and we may coerce to another type if the default type does not match the type required by its context. In the case of $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^ω$, type coercion is not needed, but in the case of paths and subgraphs, it is needed unless we wish to keep having to make the coercion explicit.
In the cardinal/ordinal example, it does not have type coercion, but it does have operation overloading. The desire to overload operations is one key reason for wanting type coercion!
For another example, any ring R has its own additive and multiplicative identity, but we always want to write "0" and "1" for them, in which case we must understand these as being coerced to the right type (i.e. element of R) when used in an expression involving arithmetic within R. This is especially useful when talking about polynomial functions, if we want it to behave the way we intuitively expect. Specifically, if we want an integer polynomial function $f$ to be such that you can put in any element of any ring and get back the output you want, then you need $f$ to accept any object $x$ that has a default type as an element of some ring, so that you know how to obtain powers of $x$ and know how to multiply it by an integer. But that is not enough; you want to be able to write $f(x) = x^2+1$ for any ring $R$ and element $x$ of $R$, right? In that case, you need automatic type coercion for $1$. The $+$ and exponentiation are overloaded, which in turn tell you that you need the "$1$" to be an element of $R$, so you do that coercion. Which coercions are valid ought to be defined clearly too; in the case of any ring $R$ we conventionally permit coercion from members of $ℤ$ to an element of $R$.

You are reading it correctly. Based on your definitions, a path and a cycle are subgraphs, as they are a collection of vertices of edges, but the converse is not necessarily true. For example, you can easily pick a disconnected set of vertices and relevant edges between them and that is indeed a subgraph, although it is not a path or a cycle.
Of course, some people define paths differently, for example, I learned it as a sequence of vertices such that adjacent vertices are connected by an edge, but others know it as a sequence of edges. However, based on the definitions you have provided, paths are indeed subgraphs.

Thank you for your answer. I see a difference. A path denotes a sequence; however, there’s no sequence in a subgraph

Does my comment make sense to you?

@F. Zer you are way to literal here. Just take a path (which is defined as a sequence or whatever) and then take the vertices $V'$ and edges $E'$ that make up this path, then $(V',E')$ forms a subgraph in terms of the definition you gave us.

Thank you @schiepi. I'll think about that. I saw that an n-tuple like a path was structurally different than a pair (V', E').

Paths and their corresponding subgraphs can't be completely conflated, because for any path, there is a reverse path which corresponds to the exact same subgraph. The path which starts at $x$ and ends at $y$ is not the same as a path which starts at $y$ and ends at $x$ (unless $x=y$). A path can be casted as a subgraph by deleting the information about orientation, but a subgraph can't be casted to a unique path without making an arbitrary decision about orientation.

Thank you so much for your input @Jade Vanadium. I thought about orientation while crafting my answer.
